# Delphi : how to disable TWebBrowser security certificate alert?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm programming a Delphi application which uses a TWebBrowser to display Google maps on the form. But when it starts to navigate to the HTML file, an alert is shown several times (about 10 times): "`revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available ...`"

How can I prevent TWebBrowser from doing that? I mean disabling the security warning? Do I have to add an exception for Google and my file? If yes, how? Some code would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the TWebBrowser component has a property called "Silent" that when set to "true", prevents such dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet to help out. Set Silent to true, this will stop the browser window from showing any dialog boxes. This will do what you want, but if there is any issues, they will not be displayed due to any windows showing is disabled.

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  WebAddress : string;
begin
  WebAddress := 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Orlando,+FL/@28.4810971,-81.5088354';
  WebBrowser1.Silent := true;
  WebBrowser1.navigate(webaddress);
end;
```

If you don't mind what address are you trying to reach, so see the security warning?

Answer (score -3):

Uncheck the 'Check for server certificate revocation' and 'Check for publishers certificate revocation' settings at Control Panel --> Internet Settings --> Advanced tab

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the certificate rather than switching off warnings?

Comment: Fix the certificate is better, but since the question is ...to disable the security warning...

Comment: The asker of the question just needs educating that there is a better solution

Comment: @Hendra The `delphi` tag, however, suggests that the question is how to do that programmatically.

Comment: This answer involves the user disabling security checking for the entire system. If that's really the only way, then so be it, but you should explicitly *say* that that's the only way. Otherwise, more delicate approaches would be better, such as detecting and quelling the error for the one specific program where it matters. It seems that fixing the certificate would be another way to make the error go away, though. Or could it be that the alert is true, and that the solution lies in merely making revocation information available (somehow)? This answer seems to be the solution of last resort.

Comment: Agreed. And no, my answer is not the only way. My previous answer just a quick respond to the question. The problem could be the result of either the client computer could not reach the Certificate Authority server, i.e. firewall/proxy setting or the CA server is simply down (which is hopefully interminent), or the Google maps server has problem. From the application perspective, it would be better to catch the error, display a custom message error stating the problem, and give the user options to deal with it.

Comment: the asker of the question obviously is talking about a client side, TWebBrowser component based solution. A system-wide setting or a server certificate change (whoa!!!) is completely irrelevant to the question, and might not even be possible at all, depending on users control.

Comment: as for a workaround, I'd suggest a look at CEF (chromium). That component does have an event that triggers in such cases, and that you can prevent from showing dialogs simply by settings "Handled := true" in that event.